# pip install breaks due to SSL certs

Tags: flask, installation, pip

When I try to do a pip install Flask I get some ssl errors. If I try to add exceptions there is no difference. I googled around and see some discussion on this from a year ago but nothing else (see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5063)

```
(venv) pip install -U flask --trusted-host=pypi.python.org --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org
Collecting flask
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/flask/: There was a problem confirming 
the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flask (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for flask
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE :  THIS MIGHT ALREADY SOMETHING THAT YOU HAVE TRIED**

This is probably due to the fact that you are using `--trusted-host=pypi.python.org` .
This has happened since sometime during April 2018, the Python Package Index was migrated from `pypi.python.org` to `pypi.org`. This means "trusted-host" commands using the old domain no longer work.

So the command you are looking for would be `pip install -U flask --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org`.

For furthur details , have a look at this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29751768/13685399).